# jQuery background color change on separate functions

Tags: javascript, css

[Stripped down working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bayken37/k1xfehrq/92/)

I have rows being highlighted if their checkbox is checked. It works on one table but for some reason I can't see why it's not doing the same on the other. All other functionality is exactly how I want it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#myteam').on('change', '[type=checkbox]', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var row = $this.closest('tr');
    if ($this.prop('checked')) { // move to top
      row.insertBefore(row.parent().find('tr:first-child'))
    } else { // move to bottom
      row.insertAfter(row.parent().find('tr:last-child'))
    }
  });
  $('#otherteam').on('change', '[type=checkbox]', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var row = $this.closest('tr');
    if ($this.prop('checked')) { // move to top
      row.insertBefore(row.parent().find('tr:first-child'))
    } else { // move to bottom
      row.insertAfter(row.parent().find('tr:last-child'))
    }
  });
  $('td:first-child input').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('#myteam tr').toggleClass("highlight", this.checked);
  });
  $('td:first-child input').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('#otherteam tr').toggleClass("highlight", this.checked);
  });
});
```

Comment: can you create a share the html as well

Comment: The jsfiddle behaves correctly?

Comment: everything works well except when you check a box on right side, the row is not highlighted like on the left side

Comment: @Josh i see that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem `$('td:first-child input')`, remove `:first-child` in the second change event will be what you need because it isn't the first child.

Answer (score 2):

As **K.Angel7** mentioned, minor issue with the jQuery selector.

I fixed the jsfiddle and here you go:
http://jsfiddle.net/Manoj85/k1xfehrq/98/

```
  $('#otherteam td input').change(function() {
    console.log("Other Team");
    $(this).closest('#otherteam tr').toggleClass("highlight", this.checked);
  });
  $('#myteam td input').change(function() {
    console.log("My Team");
    $(this).closest('#myteam tr').toggleClass("highlight", this.checked);
  });
```

Always, consider adding specific parent, in your case, #myteam and #otherteam. It would be better for maintenance of any updates in future.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to make your selector more precise.

```
$('#myteam td:first-child input').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('#myteam tr').toggleClass("highlight", this.checked);
});
$('#otherteam td:first-child input').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('#otherteam tr').toggleClass("highlight", this.checked);
});
```

However, it would be simpler to move the highlight toggle into the other change function.

```
$('#myteam').on('change', '[type=checkbox]', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var row = $this.closest('tr');
  if ($this.prop('checked')) { // move to top
    row.insertBefore(row.parent().find('tr:first-child'))
  } else { // move to bottom
    row.insertAfter(row.parent().find('tr:last-child'))
  }
  $this.toggleClass("highlight", this.checked);
});
$('#otherteam').on('change', '[type=checkbox]', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var row = $this.closest('tr');
  if ($this.prop('checked')) { // move to top
    row.insertBefore(row.parent().find('tr:first-child'))
  } else { // move to bottom
    row.insertAfter(row.parent().find('tr:last-child'))
  }
  $this.toggleClass("highlight", this.checked);
});
```

That should answer the question. But, I noticed the functions could be simplified. You can replace all of the code posted with just these lines:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myteam, #otherteam').find(':checkbox').change(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var row = $this.closest('tr');
    if (this.checked) { // move to top
      row.prependTo(row.parent())
    } else { // move to bottom
      row.appendTo(row.parent())
    }
    row.toggleClass("highlight", this.checked);
  });
});
```

Note that the `:checkbox` is a [jquery-defined psuedo-selector](https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/)

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhkb53n0/) where I refactored some more stuff.

Comment: great, i assumed there was a way to make it more efficient.. but for my level i had to do them separately to get them to work first

Comment: @Josh smart thinking